# Scripts that run when linux starts / stops?

Tags: linux

What is the easiest way in Linux to have a script run on startup and another on shutdown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SysV style init.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SysV-style)

See the introductory article http://www.linux.com/feature/114107

Most distros have their own front-end to manage runlevels. Unfortunately there is no standard tool.

For example I use OpenSUSE, where it can by [managed by YaST](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/opensuse_guides/opensuse11.1_reference_guide/sec_boot_init.html).

Comment: Not all distros use SysV, either.

Comment: Most do. InitNG and Upstart are still experimental.

Comment: I wasn't talking about InitNG and Upstart, I was talking about the somewhat modified BSD-style init in Slackware and some related distros.

Comment: On Slackware for example, you would add a /etc/rc.d/rc.whatever script to stop/start your service, then edit the runlevels' startup script to run your script. You'd want to tell runlevel 0 (halt) to stop the service, and runlevel 3 (multiuser) to start the service.

Comment: I see there is bit of confusion. SysV init consist in runlevels defined in /etc/inittab. Slackware of course uses that. Now, what you're talking about is rc.d init scripts, which indeed are called SysV or BSD style, so it might be confusing. In fact I think most distros use hybrid of both.

Answer (score 4):

In Debian or Ubuntu, copy /etc/init.d/skeleton, an example script for starting/stopping daemons, and edit it to your liking, and make it executable:

```
cp /etc/init.d/skeleton /etc/init.d/mythingy
pico /etc/init.d/mythingy
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/mythingy
```

That should provide a way for you to start and stop a given program/script. You may want to test your script to make sure that it works as expected:

```
/etc/init.d/mythingy start
/etc/init.d/mythingy stop
```

After doing this, use the update-rcd command to make it run at startup/shutdown:

```
update-rcd mythingy defaults
```

Unless you know what you are doing, using the defaults is perfectly fine. That should be all you need to do!

You might find these resources helpful:

1. [Debian SysV Init](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s-sysvinit)
2. [Ubuntu Init](http://www.linux.com/feature/125977?theme=print)

Answer (score 2):

Create the script in /etc/init.d and run `chkconfig myscript on`. See the other scripts in /etc/init.d for examples.

As others have pointed out, this is on a Red Hat based distribution.

Comment: -1: chkconfig does not exist in my Linux. You might want to mention what distribution you’re using.

Comment: This is distribution dependant. You can't assume chkconfig is there.

Comment: Just to add to this, chkconfig relies on a very specific set of comments near the top of the script to tell it which runlevels to start and stop at.  Also, it's mostly found in RedHat-based distros.

Comment: Command is update-rc.d in debian based distros. Scripts still in /etc/init.d (standard?)

Comment: Not all distros use sysv-style init. My distro of choice (Slackware) uses BSD-style with some borrowed sysv-isms, and I think there are a couple of more obscure set-ups too (ISTR hearing that Gentoo does its own thing, but I'm not familiar with it).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has /etc/rc.local, a script which you can edit to call anything you need to do on startup.

Gentoo has /etc/conf.d/local.start and /etc/conf.d/local.stop

Must be something similar under Redhat/fedora.

Answer (score 0):

This is very distribution-dependent, and also varies with stuff like runlevels, and exactly when during start-up you want your script to run.

But poking around in /etc is probably a good way to figure out how to do it for your particular machine.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make a script run on startup is to add a @reboot entry in root's crontab. (I don't know of any @shutdown rule):

```
@reboot /path/to/script <arguments>
```

For debian systems (ubuntu included), the "correct" way is to make an init script in /etc/init.d based on the skeleton file in that directory. Use update-rc.d to make it active (read the man for usage).

Answer (score 0):

If your application does not support daemonizing, pid file handling, etc, you can use the command [start-stop-daemon](http://man.he.net/man8/start-stop-daemon) to provide these features for you in your init script.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified which distro, all you can rely on is the information from LSB about [init scripts](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/LSB_3.2.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/initsrcinstrm.html).